# Bazel Build - Server Execution failed

Tags: angular, angular7, bazel, angular8

I have upgraded my angular application from angular 7 to 8. It was a smooth upgraded and also I have added bazel to my application. When I give ng build I'm facing `Server Execution failed`.

```
D:\Angular\Angular8\Web>ng build
INFO: Analyzed target //src:prodapp (1 packages loaded, 1 target configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: D:/angular/angular8/web/src/BUILD.bazel:10:1: SassCompiler src/global_stylesheet.css failed (Exit -1)
  s e r v e r   e x e c u t i o n   f a i l e d
Target //src:prodapp failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.

ERROR: D:/angular/angular8/web/src/BUILD.bazel:58:1 SassCompiler src/global_stylesheet.css failed (Exit -1)
INFO: Elapsed time: 135.134s, Critical Path: 120.92s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
D:\Angular\Angular8\Web\node_modules\@bazel\bazel\node_modules\@bazel\bazel-win32_x64\bazel-0.28.1-windows-x86_64.exe failed with code 1.
```

Ths SassCompiler throws me the errror.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Install using [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/)
Install the Chocolatey package manager

Install the Bazel package:

choco install bazel
This command will install the latest available version of Bazel and its dependencies, such as the MSYS2 shell. This will not install Visual C++ though.

See [Chocolatey installation](https://bazel.build/windows-chocolatey-maintenance.html) and package maintenance guide for more information about the Chocolatey package.

Reference:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31241

And also we need to install MSYS